# bootstrap affix. page/scrollbar jump to the top of the page, when scroll bar reach to affix offset

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I searched in questions. but i could not find the answer.
This is a simple html code for using bootstrap affix.

```
<div style="height: 160px;background: blue;"></div>
<div style="background-color: green" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="200">
    foo
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    foo
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    foo
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    foo    
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k5fv4b0x/

I cant scroll to bottom of the page. see your self in jsfiddle.
when scroll bar reach 200 from top, its jump to top of the page.
Idk its from my os/brower or my code.

Comment: That's because the affix div is the last thing on the page, so when it's "affixed" via `position: fixed;` it decreases the overall height of the page and you're no longer scrolled > 200px down on the page, so it will no longer be affixed. You need some content below the affixed div so that you can stay scrolled > 200px when the affixed menu triggers and becomes fixed. https://jsfiddle.net/k5fv4b0x/2/

Comment: in your code. affix div is disappear in middle of the scroll/page.
and also. i need affix div, remain in 100% height of the page.

Comment: it doesn't disappear, it's `position: fixed;` as bootstrap's affix is designed to do. If you want to style it different, style it with `#aff`. Here it is styled to be 100% of the height of the page when it's affixed. https://jsfiddle.net/k5fv4b0x/3/

Comment: i think its more complicate. i just test your code with `height: 300` for first div. it work in jsfiddle but not in my own brower. i think its because of size of screen. so this is not work in all situations

Comment: Of course screen height matters - that's what determines when a scrollbar appears, and affix fires after you've scrolled a certain amount.

Comment: k. tnx for your help